# Moving facet labels that have two lines near the plotting area

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, facet

I’m working with faceted plots and I’m having an issue trying to move facet labels that have two lines near the plotting area.
Consider the minimal example:

```
require(ggplot2)

labs <- as_labeller(c(`0` = "LABEL 1", 
                      `1` = "LABEL 2 HAS TWO LINES\nBECAUSE IT'S TOO LONG"))   

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, drat)) +                      
  geom_point() + 
  theme_bw() +
  geom_hline(yintercept=2, linetype="solid") +
  geom_vline(xintercept=50, linetype="solid") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(50,500), expand =c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(2, 5), expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), 
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(size=9),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  facet_wrap(~am,  labeller = labs) 
p
```

[image]

Now adding `vjust=-0.62` to move the facet labels near the plotting area we have the following:

```
p + theme(strip.text = element_text(size=9, vjust=-0.62))
```

[image]

As you can see only LABEL 1, the single line label, is moved close to the plotting area - and that’s the problem.
I wished that both labels could have moved. Does anyone have any suggestion?
*Observation: I’m working with a considerable amount of faceted plots so making and customizing plots one-by-one doesn’t seem to be a good idea.

Comment: so you need label1 to paste at origin(0,0)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this may helpful for you

```
p + theme(strip.text = element_text(size=9, vjust=1))
```

[image]